# ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' in my django project

Tags: python, django, apache

I deployed my django site online on apache in mod_wsgi everything works so far
I then installed:

`pip install --pre xhtml2pdf`

to generate pdf documents
with the code that goes with it, after restarting the server and when I refresh my site I have an Internal Server Error error,
And then after consulting the error.log file
I have this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/home/ubuntu/myproject/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

And when I run from the command line, I get no error.

```
Python 3.10.7 (main, Nov 24 2022, 19:45:47) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from PIL import _imaging as core
>>>
```

this has to do with wsgi or??
where is the problem ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem a while ago, if you are using Linux/Ubunut then you can try installing the libjpeg library and its development files, which are required for PIL to work correctly.

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`

After you've installed the dependencies, try reinstalling the PIL package:

`pip install Pillow`

Once PIL is installed correctly, restart your server and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade this package using below command:

```
pip install -U Pillow
```